# Win10 Unable to boot - Srttrail.txt Bluescreen / 0xc0000001 Error

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, bsod, bcdedit

Srttrail.txt Bluescreen Error on Winows 10 x64 Desktop(with GTP Drive)

I recently purchased a software(VST plugin) which required registration with PACE iLOK Licence Manager. The installation of iLOK required restarting my PC, but has now sent my computer in a bluescreen loop:
*"Automatic Repair, Your PC did not start correctly..."*
After Startup repair not being able to repair my computer, it reffered me to a log file.
In the logfile *([C:\WINDOWS\System32\Logfiles\Srt\Srttrail.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRpsD.jpg))* I found the error codes **0x32** and **0x57** with the translated message *“Unspecfied changes in the system configuration may have caused the problem”*

I am now unable to boot my computer, even with all the WinRE startup alternatives such as  enable safemode etc… I cant even force boot safemode with `bcdedit /set {default} safeboot minimal`. I do not have any system reset points even though I used one about 3 weeks ago. So, I installed Windows Installation Media on a flash drive and tried to repair the system with it, but not even that takes me past the Windows Recovery Environment.

After a while I got this new bluescreen message: *“After multiple tries, the operating system on your PC failed to start, so it needs to be repaired. Error code: 0xc0000001.”*

**Note:** Performing a clean install of windows is my absolute last option and I am willing to try whatever might work! I have already backed up the most important files to a USB using the cmd notepad.exe trick.(Hope I made myself clear that i can't access windows)

### What I already have tried:

- Manually removing the PACE oem driver in cmd. (Did not help)
- `sfc /scannow /offbootdir=c:\ /offwindir=c:\windows` ->

  `Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations`
- `chkdsk c: /f /r /x`-> [RESULTS*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAc7E.jpg) *"Failed to transfer logged messages to the event log with status 6"*
- I also tried turning off auto repair with  `bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled no`, no luck.
- Resetting the CMOS battery-> *“Error: CMOS Checksum error-
  Defaults Loaded”*
- `mkdir C:\Scratch` `DISM /Image:C:\ /ScratchDir:C:\Scratch /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth` ->

  `Restore operation completed succesfully` but to no good it
  seems.

I tried repairing the EFI Bootloader (where “S:” is the assigned EFI
volume):

```
diskpart
select disk 0
select volume 8
assign letter=S
exit

cd /d S:\efi\microsoft\boot\
attrib bcd -s -h -r
ren bcd bcd.bak
bcdboot c:\windows /l en-us /s S: /f /all
```

Since I´m from Sweden I also tried the bcdboot command with the swedish sv-SE locale. Both cases->
`Boot files successfully created`

- `bootrec /scanos` tells me `Total identified windows installations:0`

### Images with System Info(Good to know?)

[dir C:, list part, list volume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYHzL.jpg)

[BcdEdit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3cbK.jpg)

Thankful for all the help I can get!

Answer (score 0):

Loooks like this is of no interest to anyone.

I have the same problem, the SRTTrail.txt points to "A Patch is preventing system restart".

After some googling, I found a hint to check the registry values under
ˋˋˋ
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\PackagesPending
ˋˋˋ
If there is a value named Exclusive, it shall be set from 4 to 0.

Unfortunately, that did not help in my case so I am out of solutions at that point.